# How can I name each Hexagon?

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass[border=2mm, tikz]{standalone}    
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}    
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[    
   x=7.5mm,y=4.34mm,    
   box/.style={    
      regular polygon,  
      regular polygon sides=6,         
      minimum size=10mm,           
      inner sep=0mm, outer sep=0mm,    
      draw}
 ]
\node [box] (innerbox) {};    
\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \y using {int(ifthenelse(\x+2>6,\x-4,\x+2))}] in {1,...,6}     
 \node [box,anchor=corner \y] at (innerbox.corner \x) {};    
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

I want to name, for example, the hexagons as in the following figure:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'nominate'? Nominate them for what? Presumably not elected office, but then what?

Comment: I've formatted your code for you. However, it does not compile.

Comment: Cfr - Call each Hexagon of a number, as in Figure.

Comment: You should have accepted Torbjørn T.'s answer. That was posted 1 minute before mine according to the timestamp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code cannot be compiled as is. Please check that code compiles before posting an example unless it not compiling is the question. In that case, ensure it produces the error you are asking about.

This code can't possibly work for you. It cannot possibly produce the output shown without errors because it contains paragraph breaks in all kinds of randomly weird places, which gives error after error after error.

As to the question, why can't you just use a second variable in the loop?

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  x=7.5mm,y=4.34mm,
  box/.style={
    regular polygon,
    regular polygon sides=6,
    minimum size=10mm,
    inner sep=0mm, outer sep=0mm,
    draw}
  ]
  \node [box] (innerbox) {g};
  \foreach \i/\j [evaluate=\i as \k using {int(ifthenelse(\i+2>6,\i-4,\i+2))}] in {1/a,2/b,3/c,4/d,5/e,6/f}
  \node [box,anchor=corner \k] at (innerbox.corner \i) {\j};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: honeycomb]

## EDIT

You could also simplify things so that you only need to specify the names for the nodes. For example:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  box/.style={
    regular polygon,
    regular polygon sides=6,
    minimum size=10mm,
    inner sep=0mm,
    outer sep=0mm,
    inner color=orange!75!red!50!yellow,
    outer color=orange!75!red!75!yellow,
    draw=orange,
    text=red,
  },
  ]
  \node [box] (innerbox) {7};
  \foreach \i [count=\k from 0, evaluate=\k as \j using {int(60*\k+30)}, evaluate=\j as \l using {(int(\j+180))} ] in {10,6,4,3,1,9}
  \node (h\k) [box,  anchor=\l] at (innerbox.\j) {\i};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces the following (for the bees):

[image: honeycomb for bees]

Comment: cfr - Wonderful. This solves all my problems.